# display selected dropdown value using formControlName - ReactiveForms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

I have a dropdown and i have done validation using formcontrolname. I also wanted to display the selected dropdown. So i used ngModel for this to happen. But I received an error saying

```
It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. Support for using the 
ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in 
Angular v6 and will be removed in Angular v7.
```

How can i achieve both validation and displaying selected dropdown using formControlName

My HTML code

```
 <nb-select selected="1" id="doctor" formControlName="titleName" required (change)="changeTitle($event)"
 [class.is-invalid]="form.get('titlename').invalid && form.get('titlename').touched" [(ngModel)]="selectedtitle">

   <nb-option *ngFor="let title of Title" [value]="title">{{title}}</nb-option>
 </nb-select>

<p>{{selectedtitle}}</p>
```

My .ts file

```
Title: any=['Mr.', 'Ms.', 'Mrs.'];
selectedtitle = this.Title[0];

changeTitle(e){
    console.log(e)
    this.titleName.setValue(e.target.value,{
      onlySelf: true
    })
  }

  get titleName() {
    return this.form.get('title');
  }
```

Comment: Don't use reactive form and template driven form together. You can set Default value using reactive form itself

Comment: I'm not asking about default value. I want to display the selected dropdown

Comment: Since you have created getter titleName. you can use that to acces selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use [(ngModel)] for this purpose

just use

```
<p>{{ form.value.title }}</p?
```

or

```
<p>{{ form.controls['title'].value }}</p>
```

Assuming you have formgroup as form

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

if you want to show errors validation

```
  <span class="error" *ngIf="form.controls['title'].errors.required">This field is required</span>
```

Comment: Hey, please help me out with this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839181/set-value-of-input-based-on-the-dropdown-selected-using-formcontrolname-reacti