# set value of input based on the dropdown selected using formControlName - ReactiveForms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I have an input whose value should be based on dropdown selected. here is my code

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <nb-select type="number" fullWidth id="service" formControlName="service">
      <nb-option *ngFor="let service of Services" [value]="service">{{service.name}} </nb-option>
  </nb-select>
</div>

<input type="number value="service.price">
```

My .ts file

```
Services: Array<any>=[
    {name: 'Consultation', price: 100}, 
    {name: 'Follow Up', price: 200}, 
    {name: '24 Hrs. Creatinine', price: 300}, 
    {name: 'Complete Blood Count - CBC', price: 400}, 
    {name: 'X-Ray', price: 500}];
```

So when Consultation is selected, input value should be 100. Similarly when X-ray is selected, input value should be set to 500.

I want to use formControl only. ngModel is not required.
Help me how can i acheive this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="number" value="{{form.controls['service'].value.price}}" />
```

I assume your formgroup is "form"

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [(ngModel)] on the input field? with the ngModel binding towards the form control value equivalent

you could use callback funtion in the .ts file and the ngModel would be equal to it.

example:

```
getPriceEquivalent = () => {
    this.Services.forEach(x => {
      if(x.name === this.service.value){
         return x.price;
      }
    }); 
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: i don't want to use ngmodel. Because if i use both ngModel and formcontrol, I'm receiving an error. saying "It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. Support for using the 
ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in 
Angular v6 and will be removed in Angular v7. "

Comment: So just create a formControl for the price input and a change listener on the top and anytime the listener is triggered you set your price formControl value to the equivalent of the name written in the top form control.